# Run the .exe file from command prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I have developed the program in C# using Visual studio and generated .exe file in Debug folder. I have also added command line arguments in Properties-> Debug.

The params passed are D:\Example\bin\Release\Input_Files\ D:\Example\bin\Debug\trycc.css 900 640

Running this solution by marking the solution configuration as Debug, it generates .exe file in Debug folder.

When the same i try to run from the command line it tells, unable to open some file which is present in the same level as .exe.

```
 D:\>D:\Example\bin\Debug\Example.exe D:\Example\bin\Release\Input_Files\ D:\Example\bin\Debug\trycc.css 900 640
```

I am not understanding where I am going wrong. Kindly help.

Here it is :

```
D:\>D:\Example\bin\Debug\DFu1.exe  "D:\Example\bin\Release\I
nput_Files\"  "D:\Example\bin\Release\Input_Files\css\screen.css" "900
"  "830"
Incomplete Arguments entered.
Press any key to continue


 Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part
 of the path 'C:\Out\elogs.txt'.
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, I
 nt32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions o
 ptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
 at ExampleParser.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Example\Program.cs:l
 ine 691
```

Comment: This is likely a problem with working directory, or you need to put your parameters between quotes " ". Can you copy-paste whole output from Command Prompt? If you don't know how - right click on Command Prompt window, Mark, select the lines, right click and it'll be in your clipboard (you can than CTRL+V here).

Comment: I have edited.. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

May be you problem is incorrect quotation. Try to pass this arguments:

```
"D:\\Example\\bin\\Release\\Input_Files\\" "D:\\Example\\bin\\Debug\\trycc.css" 900 640
```

Or:

```
"D:\Example\bin\Release\Input_Files\" "D:\Example\bin\Debug\trycc.css" 900 640
```

Comment: In first case it shows less number of argument. And in second it throws same error as mentioned below

Comment: @Aada, please show your code where you handle arguments.

Comment: @Kirill, can you show your code at Program.cs:line 691?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are referencing a dir (folder) `D:\Out'` that doesn't exist, first make sure that dir exist if it is the correct dir.  If it is not, chances are the app is using relative path (e.g. `..\SomeDir\`) rather than absolute path, thus the code needs to change to correctly locate this dir.  A simple, yet quick way to prove the app works, is to first cd into the dir where it is located and run the exe from that path:

```
cd D:\Example\bin\Debug

Example.exe D:\Example\bin\Release\Input_Files\ D:\Example\bin\Debug\trycc.css 900 640
```

If you in fact have relative path, remember that if the app (.exe) is in `D:\Example\bin\Debug` and you have a dir `D:\Example\bin\Out` and the code tries to read/write to that "Out" dir using `..\Out`, it will succeed if the app is run directly from *\bin\Debug*.  But if you run the app from `D:\MyOtherDir\Test` (yes, even if you pass in the full path *D:\Example\bin\Debug\Example.exe*), it will resolve to **D:\MyOtherDir\Out**, relative paths are based upon the current working dir, not where the exe is located.